# Update panel not adding new controls but shows the new ones

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Well when working with a simple example it works but when I load a control from other panel and build and then add it to update panel it doesn't update the controls of it. The example here is working :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelRepeater" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="allAccResults" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ListBox ID="lbLog" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button ID="loadMoreAccResultsButton" CssClass="loadMoreAccResultsButton" runat="server" Text="load More" OnClick="loadMoreAccResultsOnPanel" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When async post back happends it triggers below the function and it works fine by adding controls

```
        lbLog.Items.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        allAccResults.Controls.Add(lbLog)
```

When I load a control and build it and then add it to panel it only adds the new ones not every new one control to the previous added so it ends up adding only new controls every time while I need all controls from beggining to end

```
        For icount As Integer = TenResultsDataStart To TenResultsDataEnd
            m_rbNum = m_rbNum + m_resPerPage
            m_accsingleresult = New AccomodationSingleResult
            m_accsingleresult = LoadControl("AccomodationSingleResult.ascx")
            m_accsingleresult.BuiltControl(m_accResults(icount), m_rbNum)
            allAccResults.Controls.Add(m_accsingleresult)
        Next
```

Also when debugging allAccResults.Controls.Count is not increasing from 10 to 20 to 30 it just clears it every time without any line code doing Clear of controls and keeps doing it 10 then again from 0 10 and again and again

Comment: Even with UpdatePanel there is a full postback of the page so everything resets every time. You might need variables in your code to keep track of all updates and reload the controls using the variables. [There might be an easier way. Can't remember now.] If you can add a complete example it will be easier for people to test.

Comment: If you want to test you could try adding controls from a new page like AccomodationSingleResult that builts these controls and adds them after builting in update panel as above. I want update panel to loop through them and remember the old controls after page cycle. You could use just simple controls like a label or text but if you create 10 and then another 10 updatepanel should show 20 and then 30 etc.

Comment: One problem is that on every call you're adding the listbox to the panel `allAccResults.Controls.Add(lbLog)`, but that can only happen one time. I think you'd have to create a new listbox each time or try a different way.

Comment: Ok I have figure it out with what @wazz suggested I just add new panels and works as I want. Below is my solution , not perfect just in case anyone can be helped from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found out how it can be done by adding a new panel every time and the new controls in each new panel.
So I just add a counter in page load in a session and if it's async postback then it will increment.

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not (Page.IsPostBack) Then
        Session.Item("IndexOfAll") = 0
        loadMoreAccResultsOnPanel()
    End If
    If (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack) Then
        Session.Item("IndexOfAll") += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

And the function that is triggered from button with async postback

```
Protected Sub loadMoreAccResultsOnPanel()

    For i As Integer = 0 To Session.Item("IndexOfAll")
        Dim pnl As Panel = New Panel()
        pnl.ID = "PAnel" & i.ToString()
        Dim m_accsingleresult As WebUserControl1
        m_accsingleresult = New WebUserControl1
        m_accsingleresult = LoadControl("WebUserControl1.ascx")
        m_accsingleresult.ID = "m_accsingleresult" & i.ToString()
        m_accsingleresult.builtcontrol()
        allAccResults.Controls.Add(pnl)
        pnl.Controls.Add(m_accsingleresult)
    Next
End Sub
```

As for the WebUserControl1

```
Public Sub builtcontrol()
    lbLog.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        lbLog.Items.Add(i.ToString() + "___" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```